# Is there any tooling to profile "hanging" RxJS subscriptions in Angular 5 apps?

Tags: angular, debugging, rxjs, rxjs5, tooling

In Angular apps, especially when NGRX is used, we have a lot of RxJS subscriptions. And yes, we (developers) may forget to unsubscribe. Is there any tooling that can help profile the issue?

Comment: Chrome dev tools. There will be a growth of leaked observable objects.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't answering for the tooling, I don't know anything else than browser dev tools that could be used here.

To ease the pain of handling unsubscribe in Angular components I've used the following. It's easy to refactor in if missing, easy to note if it's missing & can be used as a standard way to handle unsubscribe.

```typescript
// On Destroy hook
private onDestroy: Subject<void> = new Subject();
```

In method remember take(1) should come after takeUntil it might be that observable doesn't fire even once.

```typescript
this.regions$.pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy)).subscribe(...
```

And when component gets destroyed

```typescript
public ngOnDestroy() {
    this.onDestroy.next();
    this.onDestroy.complete();
}
```